# Cannot get rid of duplicate values in populated listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have tried to look at other solutions, but I cannot seem to find the answer. I am currently using a listbox to show data from the database using a sqldatasource. It is populated after I select a value from a dropdownlist before hand. When using the listbox I want to save the selected items after I click it so I set AppendDataBoundItems to true. It seems when I set it to false, I no longer get duplicates values, however then I cannot keep the selected value of the listbox after binding. I have also tried to enable/disable the view state but no luck. I am positive that I am using the DISTINCT keyword in my query but still no luck.

ASP.Net

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ProgramDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Program" DataValueField="ProgramID">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ReportPeriodDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="ReportLabel" DataValueField="DataCollectionPeriodID" Height="21px" Width="172px">
</asp:DropDownList>

<div style="width:400px; height:auto; overflow:auto; text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; left: 0; right: 0">
    <asp:ListBox ID="FormSectionListBox" DataSourceID="FormSectionDataSource" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="FormSection" DataValueField="FormSectionID" AppendDataBoundItems="True" EnableViewState="False">
    </asp:ListBox>
</div>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="FormSectionDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$     ConnectionStrings:SmartFormConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT FormSection, FormSectionID     FROM Core.FormSection_Lkup
where formsectionid IN (select formsectionid from core.form_section_subsection_item_rel where datacollectionperiodid = @datacollectionperiodid) order by FormSection">
    <SelectParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ReportPeriodDropDownList" Name="datacollectionperiodid" PropertyName="SelectedValue" DefaultValue="" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _connection = DataAccess.SelfRef().GetConnection();

    string eTarget = Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eTarget)) return;
    var list = InstructionDropDown.SelectedValue;
    switch (list)
    {

        case "Form Section":

            FormSectionListBox.DataSourceID = "FormSectionDataSource";
            FormSectionListView.DataBind();

            RenderView(FormSectionListView, "hidden"); // hide listview on page load
            break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: You mention that you use `DISTINCT`, but where?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I will show my sql datasource

Comment: Your sql query uses `SELECT DISTINCT FormSection, FormSectionID`. You know that `DISTINCT` compares both columns, so if you have `FormSection='Section A';FormSectionID=1` and `FormSection='Section A';FormSectionID=2` both are different.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, I just tested through sql to make sure, and for the testing case I am using, even without distinct no formsection is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you just have to ensure that the list is not filled on every postback:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
        // do what you need on the initial load
     }
}
```

If you need to handle the `DropDownList` selection use the appropriate events. In this case the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
protected void InstructionDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = InstructionDropDown.SelectedValue;
    switch (list)
    {
        case "Form Section":
            FormSectionListBox.DataSourceID = "FormSectionDataSource";
            FormSectionListView.DataBind();

            RenderView(FormSectionListView, "hidden"); // hide listview on page load
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have tried !Page.IsPostBack however in my application My first dropdownlist populates my second dropdownlist, which in turn automatically populates my listbox based on the first value in the second dropdownlist. When I use !PageIsPostBack, it does not populate it at the beginning because the second dropdown is a postback but I want it to show. I hope this is clear.

Comment: I will try to use the selectedindexchanged to see where I can get

Comment: There must be something else that I am missing because even when using !Page.IsPostBack and SelectedIndexChanged it still shows duplicates. Is there any way to work around the AppendDataBoundItems Property?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a work around. I set the AppendDataBoundItems to false. And used the SelectedIndexChanged Property to save the selected index after Binding.

```
protected void FormSectionListBoxSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = FormSectionListBox.SelectedIndex;
    FormSectionListBox.DataSourceID = "FormSectionDataSource";
    FormSectionListView.DataBind();
    FormSectionListBox.SelectedIndex = item;
}
```